# Samba folder is gone

Tags: 12.04, networking, samba

I seem to have some issues sharing folders from my Ubuntu 12.04 machine to a Win7 machine. After playing around with the settings, I decided to revert to Samba's original setting by reinstalling it:

```
sudo apt-get purge samba
sudo rm -rf /etc/samba/ /etc/default/samba
sudo apt-get install samba
```

just to be sure I also run:

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common system-config-samba winbind
```

Now, I can't find /etc/samba folder any more. Even when I try to share a folder through Nautilus, I get:

```
Samba's testparm returned error 1: Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
params.c:OpenConfFile() - Unable to open configuration file "/etc/samba/smb.conf":
    No such file or directory
Error loading services.
```

Same when I try to list:

```
xxx@xxx:~$ ll /etc/samba
ls: cannot access /etc/samba: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas what I did wrong, or what other package am I missing?

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to purge the others, not only samba before reinstalling.

```
apt-get purge samba samba-common system-config-samba winbind
```

Comment: great man, thx. That was it ;)

Comment: Now I don't have the share tab included in Nautilus when I right click -> Properties on a folder.

Comment: hey, I got this error:
```dpkg: error processing package samba-common-bin (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/etc/samba/tls': Not a directory```
Do you have any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: I was able to solve using an answer of yours on another question.

Answer (score 0):

All you do is right click on any folder and click share and it installs all the apt files needed to make samba server run fine.

Comment: That's all fine and good, but for some reason it doesn't work. Windows can't detect the shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me what has worked was following the solution proposed by user Laurent in this and another question. The two solutions together solved the problem.

```
apt-get purge samba samba-common system-config-samba winbind
sudo dpkg -P samba samba-common smbclient
sudo rm -f /etc/rc*.d/*samba /etc/init.d/samba
```